# How to add event listeners to div elements?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to add an event listener to each of the div elements with the class "box" here:

```
<div class="gameBox">
            <div class="msgs">
                <p class="msg">Click in a box to play. Crosses start.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="gameTable">
                <div class="box" id="0"></div>
                <div class="box" id="1"></div>
                <div class="box" id="2"></div>
                <div class="box" id="3"></div>
                <div class="box" id="4"></div>
                <div class="box" id="5"></div>
                <div class="box" id="6"></div>
                <div class="box" id="7"></div>
                <div class="box" id="8"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="reset">Reset</div>
        </div>
```

```
let elementsArray = document.querySelectorAll(".box");

elementsArray.forEach(function(div) {
    div.addEventListener("click", function() {
        alert("AA");
    });
});
```

This is the JavaScript I have used to do this, however it does not return anything. I think the issue may be that the div element is inside another div element because the code works when I take it out of the rest of my program. Please teach me the path to redemtion.

Comment: My guess is there is something else going on since that code should work. debug it `let elementsArray = document.querySelectorAll(".box"); console.log(elementsArray);`  Your code probably runs before the elements are on the page.

Comment: Do you have teh divs sized such that it is even possible to click them?

Comment: "It does not return anything" Well, neither `forEach` nor `addEventListener` return anything. Since there's no content in the `div` elements, it's going to be exceedingly difficult to click on them as well...

Comment: Indeed, adding CSS such that the `.box` elements are visible shows that the code works: https://jsfiddle.net/qy1htmkv/. Please [edit] your question with a [mre].

Comment: this is a bit of an aside for your question, but having clickable (or otherwise interactive) elements that are just `div`s without even a `role` is going to make your site inaccessible to a lot of users - like those who rely on screenreaders, or who have to use the keyboard (you could fix it for the latter by adding key events too, but it's easier to just use an HTML button and style it as you wish).

Comment: It would be nice if the OP adds more context to the question, full codebase or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is correct. One thing you can try is to make sure that the script is being executed after the elements are added to the page. You can do this by placing your script at the end of the `<body>` element, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Here's an example:

```html
<body>
    ...
    <div class="gameBox">
        ...
    </div>
    <script>
        let elementsArray = document.querySelectorAll(".box");

        elementsArray.forEach(function(div) {
            div.addEventListener("click", function() {
                alert("AA");
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

This ensures that the elements with the `box` class are added to the page before your script runs.

Another thing you can try is to add a debug statement to your code to see if the `elementsArray` variable is actually getting populated with the elements you expect. You can do this by adding a `console.log` statement, like this:

```js
let elementsArray = document.querySelectorAll(".box");

console.log(elementsArray);

elementsArray.forEach(function(div) {
    div.addEventListener("click", function() {
        alert("AA");
    });
});
```

This will print the `elementsArray` variable to the JavaScript console, which you can access in your web browser. This will allow you to verify that the `elementsArray` variable contains the elements you expect.

Comment: Note that we have questions which are duplicates for both of these eventualities. We cannot close the question as one of those until the OP answers the clarifying questions asked in the comments. It would be better to refrain from answering questions which do not provide enough information. See [answer], the section titled "Answer well-asked questions".

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to add an event listener to the `window` object instead, and check if the clicked element is one of these `.box` elements.

```js
window.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("box")) {
    console.log(e.target.id);
  }
});
```

Comment: "One solution" - but there's no problem here. The code works fine as is (or at least it does when using standard precautions like appending the code just before `</body>`).

Comment: Sure, the code looks fine, but given that it did not work for the poster, the problem is not with the code itself, but rather (most likely) the timing of the execution of that code. My solution would remove that factor, and would work regardless of when the code is executed (mostly), and even work in cases where new `.box` elements are created later one.

Comment: "and even work in cases where new .box elements are created later one" — you should mention this _in_ your answer as this is the best reason to do it that way.